# Why doesn't jQuery function toggleClass() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        #btn {
            background: green;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(() => {
        $("#btn").click(() => {
            if ($("#btn").hasClass("green")) {
                $("#btn").css("backgroundColor", "red");
            }
            else if ($("#btn").hasClass("red")) {
                $("#btn").css("backgroundColor", "green");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <button id="btn">Button</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I want the button to change its color either to red if it's green or to green if it's red. So I use toggleClass() to implement that.
**Question:** why doesn't it work?

Comment: I think you're looking for `.css` rather than `.toggleClass` here, given the arguments you're using, and your CSS (which in particular takes no account of any classes).

Answer (score 4):

It is almost certainly working but there are no CSS rules for the class "background" in the code you posted. The function is for adding/removing an entry from the class list of an element, not for directly manipulating style object properties.

If you *do* switch from `.toggleClass()` to `.css()`, you'll find that switching a property from one value to another immediately will have no visible effect. The browser will effectively ignore the first update.

Comment: i tried to declare two classes: .green and .red and set background property to each one of them, and then use them with toggleClass(). But it doesn't work neither.

Comment: As I said, making back-to-back changes will have no visible effect. The browser does not update the view in response to every change.

Comment: You mean I can't do what I want to do or what?

Comment: Or I need to use .css() instead of .toggleClass()? again, maybe I didn't get what you're trying to say, sorry

Comment: Perhaps you could *explain* what you want to do. If what you want is for the view to "blink" from one color to another, you need to use a timer.

Comment: I want the background color to change from green to red, or from red ti green when I click on the button

Answer (score 3):

Your are change class name using toggle not the rule within the class. But you can iverride it by adding inline style, like:

```
$("#btn").css("background", "red");
```

```js
$(() => {
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                const bgColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
                
                $(this).css("backgroundColor", bgColor === 'green' ? "red" : "green");
            });
        });
```

```css
#btn {
            color: #fff;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn" style="background-color:green;">Button</button>
```

Comment: if you are putting multiple statement updating same css property then the latter one will take effect.

Comment: I do it this way: I check whether class .green is set to #btn by hasClass() function in the first if statement, and if it's so: $("#btn").css("background", "red");. Then in else if statement I check whether class .red is set to #btn by hasClass(), and if it's so: $("#btn").css("background", "green");

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm using if statement

Comment: where is the if statement?

Comment: I've described you how am I doing this in my  previous comment

Comment: I have updated the answer with snippet, have a look

Comment: Your code does work now. But mine doesn't for some reason. I've updated a snippet of code in my question, can you say what's wrong with it? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Chech the code within snippet, how background is inline-style, how I use function syntax to get button reference and `style.backgroundColor` to get current color

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly correct to use the [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method...

But the argument is a string of space separated classnames.

And, of course, you have to define those class rules in your style sheet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--script src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        #btn {
            /*background: green;*/
            color: #fff;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .red{
            background-color: red;
        }
        .green{
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(() => {
            $("#btn").click(() => {
                $("#btn").toggleClass("red green");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <button id="btn" class="green">Button</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```